# Outlook 365 Index Not Rebuilding

Tags: outlook, office365, office365-apps

My Outlook (Office 365) index was not displaying all results so I attempted to delete and rebuild the index but now it returns no results.  I followed all instructions and advice in these two places:

https://office-watch.com/2015/fixing-outlook-indexing-problems/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769651/outlook-search-returns-no-matches-found

I checked the logs and the log claims the index was deleted, rebuilt, and the index service was re-started without issue.  (The service is AUTOMATIC and RUNNING).  The search options are all correct (microsoft outlook is included in locations and msg file types are checked and 'index properties and file contents' is checked).  Also, all email accounts are included in search locations within outlook.  (Also Hyper-V is disabled in windows features).

Any advice that anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EXACT same sequence of events I encountered. Seems there is a known bug and a work-around, see:

[Outlook 365 search bug work-around](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/no-search-results-for-pop-imap-accounts-51c9d2c7-a3db-4358-afdf-50d3a9e57039)

Hope this helps